# Prepared Statement For Php

Tags: php, authentication, prepared-statement

I was following the prepared statement example on the php.net site and I cant seem to get my version to work.

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","mypassword") or die (mysql_error());

$query= $link->prepare("select * from users WHERE userid = ? AND password=password('?')");
$query->bindParam(1, $userid);
$query->bindParam(2, $password);
$query->execute();

if (mysql_num_rows($query)==1)
    {
        echo "Welcome, ",$userid,"\n";
    }
    mysql_close($link);
```

I get the error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Comment: What is the entire error message?, and the corresponding code it points to?

Comment: @jdstankosky it points to the second line ($query=$link->prepare( ...

Comment: `mysql_connect` cannot be called as an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `echo "Welcome, ",$userid,"\n";`

to

`echo "Welcome, " . $userid . "\n";`

Comment: You can pass a comma separated list of values to `echo`.

Comment: @Paul `echo "Welcome, ",$userid,"\n";` will work just fine. when using `,` with `echo`, it prints all three values without error. Only thing is that it does not concatenate them and print them as a single value which the dot operator does.

Answer (score 3):

Use `mysqli_*` like `$link = mysqli_connect(...`

Comment: @Raidenance I'm afraid I'm not 100% sure what your saying

Comment: @user818502 - you're using a mixture of mysqli_* and mysql_* functions. You need to be using the mysqli_ ones exclusively.

Comment: @user818502: When you use `mysql_connect` it only returns a `resource` and you cannot run methods like `prepare()`, `bindParam()` on it. `mysqli_connect` (notice the **i**) is the connection function in the new `mysqli` series of functions which returns an object instead of resource. On this object you can use functions like `prepare()`, `bindParam()` etc

Answer (score 0):

Change following code

```
` echo "Welcome, ",$userid,"\n";`
```

into

```
` echo "Welcome, " . $userid . "\n";`
```

This is because, PHP use ‘.’ for concatenation of a string.